# Does a.dateTimeObject.format() violates the law of Demeter?

Tags: php, oop, law-of-demeter

The class Foo has a method that must return a DateTime object.

Foo can be considered a parameter object (it implements an interface)

```
class Foo implements CustomInterface{

   function dateTime():\DateTimeInterface{}
}
```

The class "Bar" requires a Foo object in the constructor

**Does it violate the law of Demeter if Foo's DateTime object is called within Bar constructor?**

```
class Bar{

   public function __construct(CustomInterface $interface){

      $this->field = $interface->dateTime()->format('Ymd');
   }
}
```

I cannot pass the DateTime object directly in the constructor because Foo is parameter object and has other fields required to make Bar work.

I understand A.B.C violates the Demeter law if C return an object we would work on, but is it still an issue if C returns a "final" result like any string or boolean value?

**Update**

Here is the exact subtlety I was looking for regarding the law of Demeter:

> The data structure behind the Position property is immutable, and that
> means it’s safe to expose it directly.
> The client code is unable to mess up with the position’s internal
> state because it simply doesn’t have any.
> int positionX = player.Position.X;
> The law of Demeter is not applicable to the world of purely functional
> (immutable) data structures.

Source: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/law-of-demeter-and-immutability

> if in a method you're working with data structures, law of demeter is
> not applied to them because is natural for a data structure to expose
> their internal structure.

Source: https://www.fabrizioduroni.it/2018/04/25/clean-code-objects-data-structures-law-demeter/

Comment: The Law of Demeter would say your `CustomInterface` should have something like a `getFormattedDateTime` function. In practice, this causes some of the [disadvantages noted in the Wikipedia entry on the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#Disadvantages). Whether it's worthwhile is up to you.

Comment: This is where I was stuck. I "know" I should implement a `getFormattedDateTime` method but this method would have to return a string, whereas typehinting the method with a specific object to be returned guarantees it can be properly manipulated later for specific purposes. Returning any string could make the construct of B fail.

Comment: IMO, part of the evolution from junior to senior dev is knowing when to violate "laws" and "best practices". See https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/04/21/dont-let-architecture-astronauts-scare-you/ for a good article on this.

Comment: @ceejayoz, unfortunately that evolution requires years of experience. The worst advice I see senior devs giving to junior devs amounts to, "When best practices are hard to follow, then break them." If this is an edge-case scenario, so be it; but without an explanation of _why_ this scenario is an edge cage, "just use your judgement" is the worst kind of advice to give a junior dev who doesn't have the experience necessary to attain good judgement.

Comment: I would argue that most objects built into the language are roughly equivalent to scalar types in this context. Something conforming to `DateTimeInterface` is not some unknown, optional, or esoteric class from elsewhere, it's part of the fundamental landscape in which your code exists. If PHP had complex scalar types, eg: `$some_string->length()`, would these not also violate an overly-strict interpretation of LoD? Not to mention that laws like these cannot be held as absolutes outside of an ideal world, which is not where we live.

Comment: https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter/